# Counting matchings in middle levels of the Boolean lattice

Tags: co.combinatorics, matching-theory, gray-codes

Let $k$ be a nonnegative integer and consider $C_k$, the set of all subsets $A$ of size $k$ in $[2k+1]=\{1,2,\ldots,2k+1\}$ as well as $C_{k+1}$, the set of all subsets $B$ of size $k+1$ in $[2k+1]$. Consider the bipartite graph $G_k$ with vertex set $C_{k}\cup C_{k+1}$ and edges corresponding to inclusions $A\subset B$. Finally, let $M_k$ be the number of perfect matchings in the graph $G_k$.

**Question:** Where can I find evaluations of $M_k$, if not in general, at least for some values of $k$?

I know that such matchings were considered, e.g., by [Kierstead and Trotter](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00337621), in relation to the middle levels conjecture ([now a theorem](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.08249)), but I did not see tables of values of $M_k$.

Comment: You might wanna look up the name “Johnson graph”

Comment: Thanks. I also saw the related names Odd graphs and Kneser graphs. The one I am interested in is the bipartite Kneser graph $H(2k+1,k)$.

Comment: Not according to https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.09175

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson_graph and https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kneser_graph

Comment: Just read the second wiki ref you just gave me at the bottom "related graphs". It discusses $J(n,k)$, $K(n,k)$ and $H(n,k)$. The definition in my question is $H(2k+1,k)$.

Comment: Sorry, I realize I was getting very confused, and you are right: these are not Johnson graphs. I deleted some of my comments but I'll leave some that are still useful/for posterity.

Comment: By the way, from this previous MO question (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/261115/number-of-perfect-matchings-in-bipartite-graph-with-given-minimum-degree) you can see that $M_k$ is lower-bounded by $(k+1)!$, but this is probably far from the truth.

Comment: Actually I think the result mentioned in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/237976/on-schrijvers-lower-bound-for-the-number-of-perfect-matchings gives you something even better as a lower bound.